# Dataframe to_csv WITHOUT separator

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

I'm coding a Python script in order to modify a text file. Here's an extract of the file, full of both texts and tables:

```
$                                                                          
$                              PROPRIETES: COQUE                           
$                                                                          
$ ----------------------------------------------------------------------   
$ PEAU 2 PLIS PFY_SH/M18 - 10MM NIDA NOMEX RAINURE - 2 PLIS PFY-SH/M18     
$ ----------------------------------------------------------------------   
$  1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |   6   |   7   |   8   |   9   |   
PCOMP     260002          0.0000  1.E+10    HILL   20.00                   
          111121  .240-3     0.0     YES  111122  10.0-3     0.0      NO   
          111123  .240-3     0.0     YES                                  
...
$ ----------------------------------------------------------------------   
$    PROPRIETE MEMBRANE                                                    
$ ----------------------------------------------------------------------   
PSHELL    888888  888888  0.0002  888888          888888             0.0   
MAT1      888888 145.5+2             .33     0.0   1.0-6     20.           
$
```

I need to modify some of the material values, and I know that the tables cannot exceed ten columns, so I coded the following:

```
import pandas as pd

fic_mat = open('FIC_MAT.DAT', 'r')
    
# As a string so the whole dataframe stays in str
ctel = '1E-4'

fic_mat_pd = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
index_mat = 0

delimiter = 8
read_until_for_rest = delimiter*len(fic_mat_pd.columns)

# From text file to dataframe
with fic_mat as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index_mat] = [line[i:i+delimiter] for i in range(0,read_until_for_rest,delimiter)]
        index_mat = index_mat + 1
        

# Modification of dataframe
for index, row in fic_mat_pd.iterrows():
    
    #########
    ## POUR MAT1
    #########    
    ## A changer: 7eme colonne de la 1ere ligne
    if 'MAT1' in row.loc[1]:
        row.loc[7] = ctel
    
    #########
    ## POUR MAT2
    #########
    ## A changer: 3 premières colonnes de la 2eme ligne        
    if 'MAT2' in row.loc[1]:
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index+1, 2] = ctel   
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index+1, 3] = ctel   
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index+1, 4] = ctel           
    
    #########
    ## POUR MAT8
    #########
    ## A changer: 2 premières colonnes de la 2eme ligne
    if 'MAT8' in row.loc[1]:
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index+1, 2] = ctel   
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index+1, 3] = ctel   

    #########
    ## POUR MAT9
    #########    
    ## A changer: 9eme colonne de la 3eme ligne + 5 premières colonnes de la 4eme ligne
    if 'MAT9' in row.loc[1]:
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index+2, 9] = ctel
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index+3, 2] = ctel        
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index+3, 3] = ctel        
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index+3, 4] = ctel        
        fic_mat_pd.loc[index+3, 5] = ctel
```

Now, I have the dataframe I want with the correct values, I am trying to extract it as a .dat file but without a separator, in order to keep the same shape as the initial file. I tried the following:

```
# The classical
fic_mat_pd.to_csv('MAT', header=None,  index = False, sep=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=" ")
```

Output:

```
$  ------ -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------        

$                                                                                                                                                              

$                                                               P ROPRIETE S:  COQUE                                                           

$                                                                                                                                                              

$  ------ -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------        

$  PEAU  2   PLIS  PF Y_SH/M18   -  10MM   NIDA  NOM EX  RAINU RE  -  2  P LIS  PFY- SH/M18            

$  ------ -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------        

$    1      |       2      |       3      |       4      |       5      |       6      |       7      |       8      |       9      |        

PCOMP           260002                      0.0000     1.E+10         HILL       20.00                                          

                     111121     .240-3           0.0           YES     111122     10.0-3           0.0             NO        

                     111123     .240-3           0.0           YES
```

I then tried:

```
with open('MAT', 'w') as fd:
        for i in range(len(fic_mat_pd)):
            print(fic_mat_pd.iloc[i,:], sep='', file=fd)
```

Output:

```
   Name: 11, dtype: object
    1     $ ------
    2     --------
    3     --------
    4     --------
    5     --------
    6     --------
    7     --------
    8     --------
    9     --------
    10          \n
    Name: 12, dtype: object
    1     $ PEAU 2
    2      PLIS PF
    3     Y_SH/M18
    4      - 10MM 
    5     NIDA NOM
    6     EX RAINU
    7     RE - 2 P
    8     LIS PFY-
    9     SH/M18  
    10          \n
```

Also tried:

```
fic_mat_file = open('MATtry','w')        
with fic_mat_file as out_file:
    write = csv.writer(out_file)
    for index, row in fic_mat_pd.iterrows():
        write.writerows(row)
```

Output:

```
$, ,M,a,t,ê,³,©

a,u,x, ,C,o,q,u

e, ,:, ,P,F,Y,-

S,H, ,e,t, ,N,O

M,E,X, ,R,A,I,N

U,R,E, ,i,s,s,u

 ,d,e, ,l,',h,ê

³,©,t,a,g,e, ,e

t, ,d,e,s, ,e,s
```

Anyone would know how to extract the dataframe without any separator in between cells?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all values of that dataframe are strings, you can use this:

```py
with open('output.dat', 'w') as fd:
    for row in df.values:
        fd.write("".join(row)+"\n")
```